# System.InvalidCastException is shown while fetching outlook mail

Tags: c#, outlook

Below exception is shown when I am trying to fetch outlook mail using WPF C#. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Outlook 2016.I am getting this exception at

```
foreach (MailItem item in oInbox.Items)
{
    a = item.Subject;
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= oInbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    a = mailItem.Subject;
}
```

line. I am not able to understand the exact issue.

**Exception** :
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

Comment: This isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application, so I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag for you. For more information, please see the tag's description.

Answer (score 0):

Your inbox contains (at least) one item which is *not* a `MailItem` (for example, a meeting invitation).

If you only want to process "classic" mail items, you need to filter on those items implementing the MailItem interface, e.g. by using `Enumerable.OfType<T>`:

```
foreach (MailItem item in oInbox.Items.OfType<MailItem>())
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, a classic type check will also work fine:

```
foreach (object item in oInbox.Items)
{
    if (item is MailItem mailItem)
    {
        // do something with mailItem 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked..!